# C++ cache friendly hash map with segregated key / values

Tags: c++, hashmap, cpu-cache

In this CppCon video, Mike Acton speaks about hash map with segregated key / values:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc

However he gives very few explanations what he means.

I tried to find more information on the topic, but I found anything.

Is there anyone who can explain me what he exactly means?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember hash map part of his speech but it must be about cache misses.

He says, at least what stayed in my mind from previous year; theoretical information that we learned in school( eg search in binary maps logN, hashes constant ... ) is good but we are working with machines and we can't ignore the way that they work. For example he gaves examples about latency. He gave different examples about l1, l2 cache misses. And shows just changing the memory layout of the data(he takes some data he is looping and carries it to another struct which helps CPU fit all data he is looping to 64bit register) he can make the same code run 10 times faster.  Also I were impressed his quote about data
"we have to understand the data, different data means different algorithm" .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any idea of what you found confusing, so I'll start with the most general overview - if you have more specific questions do ask.

I haven't watched that youtube video, but from other mentions of his work I gather his point is that it's sometimes more performant to keep the keys packed together in one area of memory, separate from the mapped-to values.  That contrasts with `std::unordered_map` which stores `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` values - clearly packing keys and values side by side in memory.  Having the keys together means less cache misses, particularly for operations like `count` that never even need to look at the values but might need to navigate past a colliding key or three.

Comment: yes, he explain same thing as you describe, but it is more complicated. I listen several times this part, but I can not follow his exact design model.